# how to take a specific child node value in xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml schema like below

```
<library>
    <book>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>abc</name>
        <read>
          <data>yes</data>
          <num>20</num>
       </read>
    </book>
    <book>
      <id>20</id>
      <name>xyz</name>
        <read>
          <data>yes</data>
          <num>32</num>
       </read>
    </book>
</library>
```

Now if the `id` is `20` i need to take the value of tag `<num>` under `<read>`

I done the code as below

```
 var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText("e_test.xml");
 var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
 var result = str.Elements("book").Where(x => x.Element("id").Value.Equals("20")).ToList();
```

this give the whole `<book>` tag with id `20`. From this how can I extract only the value of tag `<num>`.

ie is i need to get the value `32` in to a variable

Comment: Do you *actually* have an XML document, with a suitable root tag? The code you've given so far wouldn't manage to parse the XML you've given. If it did, the next problem would be with the `Where` clause. Is that what you're trying to fix, or actually the extraction of `num`?

Comment: @JonSkeet i have root tag..i didnt specified in the doc above..my only pblm is extraction of num

Comment: Well that's not your only problem, because currently the code won't match any elements... Next, are you expecting just *one* matching element, and therefore are trying to get *one* `num` value?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am getting the whole `<book></book>` with id is 20..But dont know how to extract num value from that.

Comment: Then your code isn't as you've shown us. The code you've given us would *not* match anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry i missed `"` around 20

Comment: And this is why you should always provide a [mcve] - so we can tell what the *actual* problem is rather than the problems in copy/pasting. Although I'd still suggest casting the `XElement` to `int` and performing a numeric comparison, as per my answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106195/discussion-between-sachu-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you try to extract the `num` value, you need to fix your `Where` clause - at the moment you're comparing a string with an integer. The simplest fix - if you know that your XML will always have an `id` element which has a textual value which is an integer - is to cast the element to `int`.

Next, I'd use `SingleOrDefault` to make sure there's at most one such element, assuming that's what your XML document should have.

Then you just need to use `Element` twice to navigate down via `read` and then `num`, and cast the result to `int` again:

```
// Or use XDocument doc = ...; XElement book = doc.Root.Elements("book")...
XElement root = XElement.Load("e_test.xml")
XElement book = root.Elements("book")
                    .Where(x => (int) x.Element("id") == 20)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
if (book == null)
{
    // No book with that ID
}
int num = (int) book.Element("read").Element("num");
```

Comment: what is root here?

Comment: @Sachu: The root element of the document. I felt that was a more meaningful name than `str` :)

Comment: @Sachu: Yes, but you should ask about that in a new question after doing appropriate research. (I strongly suspect there are other questions about it on SO.) If you *do* ask a new question, you should indicate what behaviour you want if `read` doesn't exist - or if `num` doesn't exist within `read`. Also state the version of C# you're using, as a C# 6 solution may well be cleaner than a C# 5 solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not dead set on using Linq, how about this XPath? XPath is probably more widely understood, and is really simple. The XPath to find your node would be:

```
/library/book[id=20]/read/num
```

Which you could use in C# thus:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myString);
var id = 20;
var myPath = "/library/book[id=" + id + "]/read/num";

var myNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(myPath);
```

Then you can do whatever you like with `myNode` to get its value etc..

Helpful reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Just be aware that if `Id` is a string variable coming from a user interface, you have the XPath equivalent of a SQL injection attack... this sort of thing is precisely why I prefer using LINQ to XML for the querying. (In general embedding one language within another, whether that's XPath, regular expressions, SQL or anything else, makes me uncomfortable...)

Comment: Good point. XPath answers the question more simply as it is asked, I feel, but Linq does indeed have the advantages you describe. Up to OP, ultimately...

Comment: Also, I'd argue that client-side validation is a potentially better solution to the injection attack problem.

Comment: No, definitely not. Not in general, at least. Why would you want to stop yourself from being able to search for a node with an element including an apostrophe, if you're actually searching for text? Basically, using LINQ to XML allows you to separate the data from the query very simply. I believe XPath *does* support parameters, but I've never used them in the examples shown in SO.

Comment: You're entirely right. I've become "not a n00b" since. My attention was drawn to this again because of an upvote.